# How to get current User Information of IBM Connection5

Tags: java, httpsession, ibm-connections

I have developed an application in Java/eclipse and i need to integrate this app as a widget to IBM Connection5. I lack one thing, i need to get the current IBM Connection 5 User Id. Is there Any way, my app can talk to IBM Connection5? and get the Current User ID of IBM Connection5. I used HTTP Session  but i supposed it is to get the user info of my app rather than IBM Connection5

Answer (score 0):

you can make a request to https:///connections/opensocial/basic/rest/people/@me/@self

You get back the user object which includes the id

```
{"entry":{"appData":{"connections":{"isExternal":"false","organizationId":"urn:lsid:lconn.ibm.com:connections.organization:20000393"}},"displayName":"User Admin","emails":[{"type":"primary","value":"ibmcnxdev.ca1@bluebox.lotus.com","primary":true}],"id":"urn:lsid:lconn.ibm.com:profiles.person:20000394"}}
```

Comment: Thanks Paul for the quick reply. But can you elaborate how can i make it possible in java. How can i make this query? I can´t able to find anything related to it.

Comment: you make an HTTP Request to your server using HttpsUrlConnection or Apache HTTP Client